# Create array formula that calculates the top 20 values

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet for calculating attendance statistics. Column I has the names of each of the members, and column H calculates the percentage of practices each member has attended. Here is the list of functions I use to calculate the top 20 people:

```
J2:  =INDEX(I$2:I$23,MATCH(LARGE(H$2:H$23,1),H$2:H$23,0))
J3:  =INDEX(I$2:I$23,MATCH(LARGE(H$2:H$23,2),H$2:H$23,0))
J4:  =INDEX(I$2:I$23,MATCH(LARGE(H$2:H$23,3),H$2:H$23,0))
J5:  =INDEX(I$2:I$23,MATCH(LARGE(H$2:H$23,4),H$2:H$23,0))
...
```

However, each time a new member joins the team, or an old member quits, I have to change each cell for 20 cells. This takes a long time to do.

Is there a way I can simplify this into one simple ARRAYFORMULA?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative Query:

```
=query(H:I,"select I order by H desc limit 20")
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I solved my own problem! If anyone else there is struggling with this just as I have, put this:

```
=query(H2:I23, " select * where I<>'' order by H desc ")
```

It will create 2 columns of information, the first column contains the percentages, and the second column contains the names in order. If you don't want the percentages, then shrink the first column as small as it can.